# Mobile Center CLI, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" When Uploading Tests

Tags: appium, calabash, xamarin.uitest, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

How to solve this error that appears when using the Mobile Center Command-Line Interface to upload tests to Mobile Center?

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error appears because you have an earlier version of Node installed on your machine.

The Mobile Center CLI, `mobile-center`, requires the latest version of Node.

Here's the steps I used to fix this error:

1. Install HomeBrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Update to the latest version of Node by entering these commands into your Terminal

   ```
   sudo brew uninstall node
   brew update
   brew upgrade
   brew cleanup
   brew install node
   sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
   brew link --overwrite node
   sudo brew postinstall node
   ```
3. Uninstall/Reinstall `mobile-center-cli` to ensure you have the most recent version of the Mobile Center CLI by entering these commands into your terminal

   ```
   npm uninstall -g mobile-center-cli
   npm install -g mobile-center-cli
   ```
4. Log into Mobile Center via CLI by entering this command into your terminal*

   ```
   mobile-center login
   ```
5. You are now able to upload your UITests to Mobile Center using the CLI

   ```
   mobile-center test run uitest --app [appname] --devices [deviceID] --app-path [LocationOfYourAppOnYour]  --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --assembly-dir [FolderContainingUITestDLL]
   ```

*If you have not yet created a password for your Mobile Center login, navigate to `mobile.azure.com`, logout of your account if you are currently logged in, then click "Forgot Password?" to create a password for your Mobile Center Account.

[image: Mobile Center Forgot Password]

Comment: Just a note that the current version of the CLI should warn you if you have an older version of NodeJS and will explicitly tell you to update. You shouldn't get the syntax error anymore.